# Run Java code with the full power of the hardware

Tags: java, runtime

I have written a simulation in Java which takes a long time to finish and give me the output I need. I now got the opportunity to run it on a high powered windows computer and let it run for days. I tried it with a data set on my laptop and it ran in eclipse for about 11 hours, on the new computer it ran 8 hours and after optimizing eclipse with all I could find it went down to 7 hours. Now I want to run it with data which is about 100x the size and it would run for about a month at this pace. It seems tho that the computer does not use much of what it is capable of when looking at the task manager.

How can I change settings to make it use close to 100% of it's memory and cpu to speed up this process as much as possible. It will not be used for other things during this time so it can consume everything the hardware has to offer.

Comment: No offense, but what the hell are you simulating?

Comment: Briefly explained, it is a simulation of voting decisions which grow complex quickly when adding more potential voters to the electorate.

Comment: Wack. Not sure how to answer your question, just curious about why you would need to run for that long. Good luck finding your solution.

Comment: Thank you, I have thought about executing it in a cloud but now that I have this hardware I will try to make the best of it.

Comment: This is far too little information for us to make a diagnosis. And Stack Overflow is likely the wrong forum for this. You need to learn how to use profiling tools and monitoring tools to see your app’s behavior in action.

Answer (score 2):

You probably aren't utilizing Threads or a ThreadPool manager. Hard to know since we have no idea what your code looks like.

You can take advantage of multiple cores by using these.

Beyond that, taking full advantage of hardware with code is the topic of Computer Science. May be time to sign up for a few classes.

Comment: You are right, it runs without threads, you are right and I am actually taking a few classes in CS next semester, this is definitely a good idea but for the problem at hand I won't be able to speed up the process much by learning CS. At this point I'm just looking to tweak settings to make it a few percent faster and maybe save me a couple of days.

Comment: Anything that can be executed on its own in parallel should be done with either a Runnable (if you don't need results) or a Callable (if you need results) submitted to a ThreadPool that takes advantage of all the cores available.

Comment: @NikNet You need to learn how to use profiling tools and monitoring tools to watch your app execute. You may have too many or too few threads. You may have bottlenecks in your code’s execution path. You may be running out of memory or thrashing virtual-memory.